# A basic question about projection map with quotient space

Tags: general-topology

I have a true-false statement as follows:

Suppose $X$ is a topological space with a quotient space $Y=X/{\sim}$ and projection map $p:X\to Y$. If $U\subseteq X$ is open, then $p(U)$ is open.

I think that the statement is false since the $p^{-1}(p(U))$ does not have to be open and it can be larger than $U$. But I couldn't find a counter-example. Could anyone give a counter-example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. For example, let $∼$ be the equivalence relation on the real line $\mathbb R$ that identifies the two
points $1$ and $−1$, and $\pi : \mathbb R → \mathbb R/{∼}$ the projection map. Then $\pi$ is not an open map. A detailed explanation can be found in Example $7.6$ of [Tu, Loring W., 
*An introduction to manifolds*, second edition].

Comment: Let $U$ be the open interval $(0,2)$. Then $p^{-1}(p(U))=(0,2)\cup \{-1\}$ is not open, which implies that so is $p(U)$. Thanks!